# Homebrew installs elm, but elm-repl not available

Tags: macos, homebrew, open-source

On MacOS 10.15.7, I installed `elm` with

```
brew install elm
```

which indeed installed the `elm` binary and placed a symlink to it into `/usr/local/bin`. However I wound that the `bin` directory for `elm` does not contain `elm-repl`. What would be the best way to get `elm-repl` in my setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You run the ELM REPL like this:

```
$ elm repl
```

See https://elmprogramming.com/elm-repl.html

Comment: I see. When I try it, it tells me to install node.js. I'm surprised that homebrew did not take care of this dependency, when installing elm.

Comment: Is it supposed to?  Not "I want it to", is it supposed to?  The formula doesn't say that it  is.  A short Google shows that most of the Elm tools outside of the compiler itself are written in Node.

Comment: My misunderstanding. I'm new to elm and thought that `elm-repl` is usually part of the distribution.